# Convert Object to byte[] in Java Card

Tags: object, serialization, deserialization, smartcard, javacard

How can I convert an object (an instance of `PublicKey`) to `byte[]` and vice versa in Java Card applets?

I am using Java Card 2.1.1 and JCDK 2.1.2.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Java Card does not provide any built-in mechanism to serialize a `PublicKey` object (or objects in general) into a byte array or to deserialize a byte array back into an object.

Consequently you would need to manually perform such serialization/deserialization. For an object that implements the `PublicKey` interface, this would mean that you would first need to find out which type of key object it is, e.g. `RSAPublicKey`. For instance, if you know that the public key is a `RSAPublicKey`, you could then extract the type (`getType()`), size (`getSize()`), exponent (`getExponent()`), and modulus (`getModulus()`) parameters and store them into a byte array. Later, you could deserialize the byte array by extracting those values and instantiating a new key using the `KeyBuilder.buildKey()` method.

Comment: 'KeyPair pair = new KeyPair(KeyPair.ALG_RSA, (short)1024);
pair.genKeyPair();'
I'm using these codes for generating KeyPair, can you give me an example for getting and setting public key of the KeyPair as and using byte array (byte[]) please?

Comment: After getting type of the public key by using getType(), you can perform casting for the key. After that, you can use the key interface method to set or get the key into byte array, e.g. RSAPrivateKey.getExponent(byte[] buffer, short offset), RSAPrivateKey.setExponent(byte[] buffer, short offset, short length), etc. Please check the javadoc for more details